# Optimize the code to run in less than 5 second

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization

In some test cases on HackerEarth following code takes more than 5 second (5.001). How can this code be even more optimized to run in less than 5 seconds?

```
tc = int(input())
ip = []
for x in range(0, tc):
    temp = []
    temp.append(int(input()))
    temp.append([int(n) for n in input().split()])
    temp.append(int(input()))
    ip.append(temp)

for it in ip:
    while not it[2] <= 0:
        for x in range(0, it[0]):
            if it[1][x] == '0':
                continue
            it[2] -= int(it[1][x])
            if it[2] <= 0:
                it.append(x+1)
                break
    print(it[3])
```

Just for reference:

### Problem Statement

Aniruddha is given a milestone M to reach in terms of distance. He is living in a different Galaxy where there are N days in a year.At the ith day he can walk atmost X distance.Assuming he walks optimally you need to output the minimum day number on which he will reach the milestone.

### Input

The first input line contains the T number of testcases. Each testcase consist of three lines First line consist of single integer N — the number of days in a year.

Next line contains N non-negative space-separated numbers— i.e. distance which Aniruddha will walk on ith day. It is guaranteed that at least one of those numbers is greater than zero.

And the third line consist of the value of milestone which Aniruddha has to reach.

### Output

For each testcase you need to output the answer to the following query.

### Constraints

```
1<=T<= 10

1<=N<=10^5

0<=X<=10^8

0<=M<=10^16
```

Comment: Have you tried the multiprocessing.pool() tool? You split up your input list into how ever many available CPU your machine has. This should speed it up significantly. Please see the documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **J. Hollom**, I have made some changes and ported the code into **Python 3.x**. Kindly note my code is designed for Hacker Earth (link given by J. Hollom) and thus it expects input!

```
test_cases = int(input())
inputs = []
for x in range(test_cases):
    temp = []
    temp.append(int(input()))
    temp.append([int(n) for n in input().split()])
    temp.append(int(input()))
    temp.append(sum(temp[1]))
    inputs.append(temp)


for item in inputs:
    item[2] = item[2] % item[3]
    if item[2] == 0:
        item[2] += item[3]
    day = 0
    while item[2] > 0:
        item[2] -= item[1][day]
        day += 1 # Since day begins at Day 1 this will give right answer!
    print(day)
```

Well, now all inputs run in less than 1 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this question comes from [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/aniruddhas-queue-4/), the goal is to find on what day of the year the milestone is reached. Therefore we are only really interested in the last year it takes to reach the milestone.

Therefore, a major speed increase in the code can be generated by simply finding out how much distance is left in that last year using the [`%`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator:

```
remainder = target % dist_per_year
```

The remainder can then be iterated over using the same approach as has originally be used. Example (written in python 2.7):

```
import random as rand
import time


def testcase(dist, milestone):
    dist_per_year = sum(dict)
    remainder = milestone % dist_per_year

    if remainder == 0:
        return len(dist)

    day = 0
    while remainder > 0:
        day = day + 1
        remainder = remainder - dist[day - 1]

    return day


milestone = rand.randint(0, 10e16)
days = rand.randint(1, 10e5)
dist = [rand.randint(0, 10e8) for i in xrange(days)]

t0 = time.time()
day = testcase(dist, milestone)
print 'Day:', day
print 'Time:', time.time() - t0
```

Comment: I guess you forgot the case when remainder is 0?

Comment: You can not simply return length of dist. Say `dist = [5, 6, 0, 0, 0]` and if remainder is 0, then answer will be day 2 not day 5! Probably best way is to run the loop once for the `dist_per_year`! Check my answer below!